# How to mock StreamedResponse body?

Tags: scala, playframework-2.3

I was writing test for following code snippet, I am getting nullPointerException for StreamedResponse body. I am not able to mock StreamedResponse body.

I tried 
`mock[StreamedResponse].body returns Source[ByteString("")]`
But getting Source.type doesn't take parameters error.

```
streamResponse map {
      case StreamedResponse(response, body) =>
        if (response.status == 200) {
          val contentType = response.headers.get("Content-Type").flatMap(_.headOption).getOrElse("application/pdf")
          response.headers.get("Content-Length") match {
            case Some(Seq(length)) =>
              Ok.sendEntity(HttpEntity.Streamed(body, Some(length.toLong), Some(contentType)))
            case _ =>
              Ok.chunked(body).as(contentType)
          }
        } else {
          Redirect(pdfService.buildEspacenetLink(ucid))
        }
    }
```

This is code where I used StreamResponse.

I want to test `case _ => Ok.chunked(body).as(contentType)` this part of code with some data as response body.

Comment: Have you tried Source(ByteString(""))? Square brackets are used to denote type parameters (think of generics in Java, e.g. List<String>), but `compiler tells you that `Source` does not have any parameters (i.e. it's not a generic)

Comment: @J0HN Yes i tried the same but it is unable to compile and returns ```missing parameter type for expanded function ((x$1) => mockStreamedResponse.body.returns(scaladsl.Source(ByteString(""), x$1)))```